# Coq Import problems with power

Tags: coq

- It seems I can't get the Coq Import system right.
- I found `pow_succ_r` in [Coq.Arith.PeanoNat](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.html).
- So I imported it and hoped it is usable

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.
Print pow_succ_r.
```

I get the following error:

```
pow_succ_r not a defined object.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the line `Module Nat` near the top of the documentation. It means that the subsequent declarations are inside the `Nat` module. So, you can access the symbol as `Nat.pow_succ_r`.

In general, if you are looking for a symbol, use the `Locate` command:

```
Locate pow_succ_r.
(*
Constant
  Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.Nat.pow_succ_r
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is Nat.pow_succ_r)
*)
```